# Feature compliance across different OS versions for the Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, version-compatibility

Are NDK features OS dependent? For example, if I have Gingerbread 2.3, can I only use NDK features for 2.3 and below, or can I take advantage of the latest fixes and features the NDK provides?

The main reason I'm asking is because it seems like the NDK is a completely different beast than the SDK, and due to the nature of C/C++ and the underlying internals of the OS should be cross version compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is as version-dependent as SDK. Each release of NDK bundles an ever-growing list of platforms. Typically, ndk-build chooses the platform according to *android:targetSdkVersion* as defined in **AndroidManifest.XML**.

Comment: So if there's a bug fix, it's only applicable to the latest version of the SDK/NDK/OS?

Comment: Not necessarily; some bugs in older NDK may be fixed for all platforms. A good example - there was a problem with compilation under cygwin in r4a, which was fixed in r4b.

Comment: Another example: r8 introduced the 4.6 toolchain for arm. It can be used for any old device.